# Can I select DOM nodes with XPath attribute patterns using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, dom, xpath

I've got a little problem: I don't know whether it is possible to select all DOM nodes with some attribute patterns using jQuery.

For example, I need to select all nodes with `id` attribute set to a string starting with `"_dom"`.

I've found something like this:

```
$("input[name^='news']").val("news here!");
```

but as far as I can see, this code applies the sample to the `<input>` nodes only.

Can I use wildcards for the node names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var nodesWithIdAttributeStartingWith_dom = $("*[id^=_dom]");
```

should do what you need.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use a wildcard to select all the nodes in the document:

```
*[id^="_dom"]
```

If you want to use XPath, you should use [Basic XPath](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/xpath) with jQuery 1.2